# Find matrices $X$ such that for any matrix $Y$ we have $\det(X^2 + Y^2) \geq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

What is the characterization of real  matrices $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that for any real matrix $Y \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$: $$\det(X^2 + Y^2) \geq 0?$$

Comment: How can you take it for granted, that $\det(X^2+Y^2) \in \mathbb{R}$? Because else you have a problem with the $\geq$-relation

Comment: The statement edit still has $\mathbb{C}$ in the notation

Comment: @RobertM you need to edit $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ as well ;-)

Comment: Is there really a problem here? I thought it was an absolutely standard convention that $z \geq 0$ for $z$ *a priori* complex means $z \in \mathbb{R}$ and $z \geq 0$...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is that $X^2$ must be a real scalar multiple of the identity matrix.
Suppose that $X^2$ is not of this form, and $n\ge 2$. Then there exists an $Y\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\det(X^2+Y^2)<0$, see [Is it always true that $\det(A^2+B^2)\geq0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438744/is-it-always-true-that-deta2b2-geq0).
Conversely, it holds that $\det(\lambda I_n+Y^2)\ge 0$ for all $Y\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$. 
My interpretation of the question is, also to determine which $X$ lead to a (permitted) real determinant, i.e., the question is to find the $X\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that $\det(X^2+Y^2)$ is real and non-negative for all $Y\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: A minor issue: it should be that $X^2$ is a nonnegative scalar multiple of $I$. Matrices like $X=I_k\oplus-I_{n-k}$ are also feasible.

Comment: Would you explain how do you conclude $\det(\lambda^2I_n+Y^2)\ge 0$  for all $Y \in M_n(\Bbb{R})$ ?

Comment: @RobertM You should read the linked post, lots of nice points.  (deleted other comment about $Y^2 = -kI$)

Comment: @user1551: yes $X^2$, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

**Proof of ill-posedness**
Let $$X = \left(\begin{matrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}i&0\\0 & 1\end{matrix}\right) \in \mathbb{C}^{2\times 2}$$
and $Y = 0_{2\times 2}\in \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$. Then
$$\det (X^2 + Y^2) = \det(X^2) = \det \left( \begin{matrix} i&0\\0&1 \end{matrix} \right ) = i \notin \mathbb{R}$$
Because $\mathbb{C}$ is not ordered, the constraint $i \geq 0$ makes no sense.

Comment: Nitpick: $\mathbb{R}$ is not well-ordered either. The issue is that $\mathbb{C}$ is not (totally) ordered at all!

Comment: The OP asks what $X$ would make $\det(X^2+Y^2)\ge0$ for all real square matrices $Y$. That is, he/she is asking for the condition on $X$ such that $\det(X^2+Y^2)$ is guaranteed to be real and nonnegative. **Such matrices do exist** (e.g. $X=0$) and the question is very well posed. Your example demonstrates an $X$ such that $\det(X^2+Y^2)$ is nonreal for some $Y\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$. It does not answer the OP's question.

Comment: You are right. The statement is edited now.

Comment: The OP's question implys $\forall X \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}: \det(X^2) \in \mathbb{R}$, which is false and so the question is ill-posed. You corrected it to "For which $X\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ is $\det(X^2 + Y^2) \in \mathbb{R} \quad \forall Y \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $\det(X^2 + Y^2) \geq 0$?"
$$$$
@CliveNewstead thanks for the correction :-)

Comment: No. The OP asks for a **characterization** of $X$, i.e. he/she means to find the characters/features/conditions such that a given statement holds. I don't know why you would think that the OP claims $\det(X^2)$ is real for *all* $X$. Nowhere in the OP's first draft (or later revisions, if that matters) of the question implies that.

Comment: Indeed for $\det(X) \in \mathbb{K}$ for $X\in\mathbb{K}^n$ and for $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{C}$ it is _impossible_ to define $z\geq 0$. That's what is meant by ill-posed. You need the _additional_ requirement $\det(X^2+Y^2) \in \mathbb{R}$ to allow for $\geq$.

Comment: Alex, although $\le$ is not a partial order on $\mathbb{C}$, the expression $z\ge 0$ is generally understood to mean $z$ is real and nonnegative. It's not "impossible to define" the expression. Would you also say the following exercise is ill-posed (I hope not.)? Find all complex numbers $c$ for which $p(z)=az^2 + bz + c = 0$ implies that $z > 0$. In other words, find conditions on $c$ so that the polynomial $p$ has only positive roots.

Comment: @SteveKass actually, I would. At least it should be more precise ($z>0$ could also be understood as $\Re z > 0$, It should be specified: Find all $c$, s.t. $\ldots \Rightarrow z\in \mathbb{R}^+$)